# Batch command for if filename contains "X"?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, contains

I'm trying to run a batch file through a folder and delete files if their name contains a certain string. I'm not sure how to check the filename against the string though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

why not just

`del *X*`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php

This is an awesome website for scripts. Loads of other stuff that might be useful if you're into scripting.